# Can I tell something from the errors of the segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault

When I run my programs via a script, I experience segmentation faults, for a certain set of parameters. I am afraid that I run out of memory. Is that so? Can I tell from the codes next to the seg. fault what happened pretty much (a bug or out of memory)?

```
./run.sh: line 3:  4833 Segmentation fault      ./eg Datasets/Klein_nb_P100000_dim100.txt 1 1 5 0 100 1 0
./run.sh: line 4:  4834 Segmentation fault      ./eg Datasets/Klein_nb_P100000_dim100.txt 1 1 5 0 100 10 0
./run.sh: line 5:  4835 Segmentation fault      ./eg Datasets/Klein_nb_P100000_dim100.txt 1 1 5 0 100 1 0
./run.sh: line 6:  4836 Segmentation fault      ./eg Datasets/Klein_nb_P100000_dim100.txt 1 1 5 0 100 2 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That number is the PID of the process that failed so there *may* be additional information if your system is set up to store core dumps by PID. Otherwise no.

Comment: That seems to be correct. Any idea how I can see if I run out of memory or not? valgrind maybe?

Comment: @G.Samaras Get a core dump and analyze it with gdb.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think I don't need it, because valgrind found: "Invalid read of size 4", thus I have a bug in my code, right?

Comment: There is definitely a bug in the code, regardless of whether or not memory has run out.